# Powershell Management.Automation ParameterBindingException

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, azure-automation

I am trying to run this command in code and using the AddArgument command for the `Select PrimarySMTPAddress` but in code I am getting a error message.

ERROR

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: 'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Select PrimarySMTPAddress'.'
```

PowerShell working

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity emailaddress -ResultSize Unlimited | Select PrimarySMTPAddress
```

c# Code

```
powerShell.AddCommand("get-distributiongroupmember");
powerShell.AddParameter("Identity", distributionGroup.Name);
powerShell.AddArgument("Select PrimarySMTPAddress");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're missing `.AddCommand("Select-Object")` (Note: `Select` is an alias of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3)) then you can chain it into `.AddArgument("PrimarySMTPAddress")` and it should work properly. I don't have access to `Get-DistributionGroupMember` but using a built-in cmdlet and a similar statement as you have:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ps1 -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object FullName
```

Would look like this:

```cs
public static Collection<PSObject> Invoke()
{
    using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
        .AddCommand("Get-ChildItem")
        .AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Filter", "*.ps1" },
            { "File", true },
            { "Recurse", true }
        })
        .AddCommand("Select-Object")
        .AddArgument("FullName");

    return ps.Invoke();
}
```

You might find it easier to bind arguments using [`.AddParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) as demonstrated above.

---

Possibly the statement for your use case would look like this:

```cs
public static Collection<PSObject> Invoke()
{
    using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
        .AddCommand("Get-DistributionGroupMember")
        .AddParameters(new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Identity", "emailAddress" },
            { "ResultSize", "Unlimited" }
        })
        .AddCommand("Select-Object")
        .AddArgument("PrimarySMTPAddress");

    return ps.Invoke();
}
```

If you want to select more than one property you can do:

```cs
        .AddCommand("Select-Object")
        .AddArgument(new string[] { "PrimarySMTPAddress", "OtherProp", .. });
```

Comment: thanks Can I add the full name too?

Comment: @Jefferson the full name? Im not sure what you mean

Comment: maybe something like this Select name,,PrimarySMTPAddress

Comment: @Jefferson gotcha, see the update